# Correct way of copying an array of char pointers?

Tags: c, memory

**Task:**

I have an array of records in `filtered_records`, with the number of filtered records in 
`num_filtered_records`. I want to duplicate this information in `binfo->filtered_records`
and `binfo->num_filtered_records` since `filtered_records` are free'd later in my code.

**Definitions:**

```
char** filtered_records;
size_t num_filtered_records;
```

**Snippet:**

```
binfo->filtered_records = malloc(num_filtered_records*sizeof(char*));

memcpy(binfo->filtered_records, 
       filtered_records,
       num_filtered_records * sizeof(char*));
```

**Issue:**

When I print `binfo->filtered_records`, I see all the records, but some of the records have
been replaced by values which are just incorrect. I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Do you want to copy the pointers to the filtered_records into the binfo->filtered_records or the actual data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are doing doesn't duplicate the actual data, **it just copies pointers**. Instead of that `memcpy`, do a for:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_filtered_records; i++)
    binfo->filtered_records[i] = strdup(filtered_records[i]);
```

If you don't have `strdup`, use `malloc(strlen(filtered_records[i]) + 1)` and then `strcpy`.

Comment: @VaibhavBajpai Were the initial strings NUL-terminated ? Show more details, do some debugging.

Answer (score 3):

You are copying the array of pointers to each value, but **you aren't copying the actual values**. So any changes which happen to the records themselves will be reflected in both the original `filtered_records` and the new `binfo->filtered_records`.

If you're releasing the memory for each record in `filtered_records` after doing the copy, then all the entries in `binfo->filtered_records` now point to invalid memory.

cnicutar's answer tells you how to safely copy the actual records.